# Using Fixed interval(3hour) data to generates continuous time(1hour) data

Tags: python, dataframe

This is part of my data:

`Day_Data   Hour_Data   WIN_D   WIN_S   TEM RHU PRE_1h
1   0   58  1   22  78  0
1   3   32  1.9 24.6    65  0
1   6   41  3.2 25.6    59  0
1   9   20  0.8 24.8    64  0
1   12  44  1.7 22.7    76  0
1   15  118 0.7 20.2    92  0
1   18  70  2.6 20.2    94  0
1   21  76  3.4 19.9    66  0
2   0   76  3.8 19.4    58  0
2   3   75  5.8 19.4    47  0
2   6   81  5.1 19.5    42  0
2   9   61  3.6 17.4    48  0
2   12  50  0.9 15.8    46  0
2   15  348 1.1 14.5    52  0
2   18  357 1.9 13.5    60  0
2   21  333 1.2 12.4    74  0`

and, I want to generate extra data like this:

[image]

the fill values are the mean of the last value and the next value.

How can I do that?
Thank you!

---

And, @jdy thanks for reminder, this is what I have done:

```
data['time']='2017'+'-'+'10'+'-'+data['Day_Data'].map(int).map(str)+' 
'+data['Hour_Data'].map(int).map(str)+':'+'00'+':'+'00'
from datetime import datetime 
data.loc[:,'Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['time'])
data=data.drop(['Day_Data','Hour_Data','time'],axis=1)
index = data.set_index(data['Date'])
data=index.resample('1h').mean()
```

Output:

```
2017-10-01 00:00:00 58.0    1.0 22.0    78.0    0.0
2017-10-01 01:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 02:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 03:00:00 32.0    1.9 24.6    65.0    0.0
2017-10-01 04:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 05:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 06:00:00 41.0    3.2 25.6    59.0    0.0
2017-10-01 07:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 08:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 09:00:00 20.0    0.8 24.8    64.0    0.0
2017-10-01 10:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 11:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 12:00:00 44.0    1.7 22.7    76.0    0.0
2017-10-01 13:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 14:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 15:00:00 118.0   0.7 20.2    92.0    0.0
2017-10-01 16:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 17:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 18:00:00 70.0    2.6 20.2    94.0    0.0
2017-10-01 19:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 20:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 21:00:00 76.0    3.4 19.9    66.0    0.0
2017-10-01 22:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-01 23:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-02 00:00:00 76.0    3.8 19.4    58.0    0.0
2017-10-02 01:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-02 02:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-02 03:00:00 75.0    5.8 19.4    47.0    0.0
2017-10-02 04:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-02 05:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2017-10-02 06:00:00 81.0    5.1 19.5    42.0    0.0
```

but, I have no idea about how to fill the NaN by the mean of the last value and the next value.

Comment: What have you tried? Ideally, we'd like to see a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for reminder, I tried to do something to solve my question at the same time   when posted my question.  so, I  added it to the question above.

Comment: And, my thinking to solve the problem maybe clumsy, so,  Looking forward to a better answer .